# v-if does not toggle element based on model value

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am attempting to hide a US states dropdown element if the country selected is not the US. I'm doing this as below:

```
<b-row v-for="demo in demographics" :key="demo.personID">
    ...
    <div class="input-group">
        <b-form-select :id="`guest-${demo.personID}-countryID`"
                        v-model="demo.countryID"
                        v-on:input="changeCountry(demo)"
                        class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-1"
                        :options="countries"
                        value-field="id"
                        text-field="name"
                        :disabled="isOwner(demo.ownerID)"
                        required>
            <template v-slot:first>
                <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>-- Select Country --</b-form-select-option>
            </template>
        </b-form-select>
        <b-form-select v-if="demo.stateVisible"
                        :id="`guest-${demo.personID}-stateID`"
                        v-model="demo.stateID"
                        class="mb-2 mr-sm-0 mb-sm-1"
                        :options="states"
                        value-field="id"
                        text-field="name"
                        :disabled="isOwner(demo.ownerID)"
                        required>
            <template v-slot:first>
                <b-form-select-option :value="null">-- Select State --</b-form-select-option>
            </template>
        </b-form-select>
    </div>
    ...
</b-row>

// change function
changeCountry(demo: TourDemographicsModel) {
    if (demo.countryID && demo.countryID == 1) {
        demo.stateVisible = true;
    } else {
        demo.stateVisible = false;
    }
}

// model
export interface TourDemographicsModel {
    // ...
    countryID?: number
    stateID?: number
    stateVisible: boolean
}
```

This works when the page is rendered, however the state visibility does not change based on someone changing the country dropdown. Ideas?

FYI - Vue v2.6 using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The input event is what v-model is using underneath the hood (it's effectively v-on:input="modelValue = $event.target.value" :value="modelValue").  This means that your input handler is not guaranteed to fire after the implicit v-model handler, so the demo object hasn't been updated yet when changeCountry is called.

The better way to do this is to use a method based on the demo object:

```
methods:{
    isStateVisible(countryId : number | undefined) : boolean{
        return (countryId && countryId == 1);
    }
}
```

now you can remove v-on:input="changeCountry(demo)" and instead do:

```
<b-form-select v-if="isStateVisible(demo.countryID)" //note the new v-if condition
                    :id="`guest-${demo.personID}-stateID`"
                    v-model="demo.stateID"
                    class="mb-2 mr-sm-0 mb-sm-1"
                    :options="states"
                    value-field="id"
                    text-field="name"
                    :disabled="isOwner(demo.ownerID)"
                    required>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that functions in v-if or v-show would not fire after the initial load. Also, I'm using Typescript so I don't have the ability to use methods: computed: etc.

Comment: v-if and v-show will get rechecked whenever isStateVisible is called, so anytime anything in this component changes.   I'm not sure what you mean by the Typescript thing, you can still use methods and computed with Typescript.

Comment: I use vue-property-decorator (https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator), so my Components are classes decorated with @Component that contain data and methods, and do not use the objects for methods, computed, data, etc. Therefore, in my component, there is no method object. In any case, I added an isStateVisible function to the component class as you suggest, and changed the v-if to call that function and it has the same result - correct on initial load but does not change when the country changes.